# error: too many arguments to function 'int rand0_toN1()'

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I can't understand the problem, I am trying to learn c++, but I never got this error before, other answers regarding this type of error were too advanced for my level and for me to follow

I use Code Blocks 20.03 on windows 10

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int rand0_toN1();

void draw_a_card();

char *suits[4]={"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"};

char *ranks[13]={"ace", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eyght", "nine", "ten", 
"jack", "queen", "king"};

int main(){
    int n, i;
    srand(time(NULL));

while(1){
    cout<<"Enter nr. of draws (0 to exit): ";
    cin>>n;
    if (n==0)
        break;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        draw_a_card();
}
return 0;

}
void draw_a_card(){
    int r,s;
    r=rand0_toN1(13);
    s=rand0_toN1(4);
    cout<<ranks[r]<<" of "<<suits[s]<<endl;
}

int rand0_toN1(int n){
    return rand() % n;
}
```

Comment: `int rand0_toN1();` -> `int rand0_toN1(int n);`.

Comment: Unrelated: I don't understand the fascination with forward declarations when they are not needed. Move `main` to the bottom of the program and just define the functions in the correct order above. `rand0_toN1`, `draw_a_card`, then `main`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Too many arguments to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007095/too-many-arguments-to-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared with no parameter

```
int rand0_toN1(); // Add parameter here
```

Your definition has a parameter

```
int rand0_toN1(int n){
    return rand() % n;
}
```